# Does using a tiling window manager make a terminal multiplexer obsolete?

Tags: terminal, display, window-manager, tmux

Since about half a year I have been enjoying a terminal multiplexer (tmux, to whomever it may concern), and have grown to like it. I would like to try a tiling WM as opposed to a stacked one some time in the future but cannot wrap my head around this simple question:

Why would one use the splits in a multiplexer within a tiling WM? Is there an upside, besides of course the single instance you'd be running?

Comment: Don't forget that most terminal multiplexers 1) work over SSH, 2) offer the ability to detach and reattach.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I have a negative answer, in that I don't particularly know an upside. I don't use `tmux` locally, relying on iTerm2's split panes and multiple windows to handle window management on my laptop. `tmux` is reserved for persistent terminal sessions on the various remote hosts where I spend most of my day.

Answer (score 0):

I never use splits in a local multiplexer session, unless I know I need to reattach from console or remotely. Local sessions are there for persistence, e.g. music player or other long running processes that do not need to depend on the GUI, which might stop unexpectedly.

Remote tmux sessions, however, are a different matter, they make it easier to do different things without logging in several times. It's convenient to have the same layout when you reattach to a session, for example I tend to run mail and RSS remotely in a tmux session.